# Messenger - How to not automatically turn group messages into MMS?

Tags: sms, mms, 5.1-lollipop

How do I prevent the lollipop (5.1) from turning my group messages into MMS?
I have some friends who can't receive MMS so this is a bit peeving.

This question has been asked before but not answered, or is for previous versions and no longer applicable.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Please check [these questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=mms+group+messages+answers%3A1), Peter – you're not the first one asking this :) Best match is probably [Send SMS instead of MMS when texting multiple people](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/58707/16575), second best [Sending single SMS message to multiple contacts causes MMS](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/45901/16575). (as you didn't mention *which* questions you've checked, I'm not sure if you've seen them. But you state "not answered", and these have answers.)

Comment: I know I'm not the first one asking this, and I checked those topics and they're no longer applicable. As the first one mentions the option was even missing in his 4.* version. And I also do not have the option to change it in hangouts.

Comment: Ah, OK. I was not sure whether the option disappeared for 4.1+ – or whether it just was introduced with a later version of Android :) Always a good idea to *explicitly* link the questions you're referring to. Avoids getting the very same questions as "recommended reading" :)

Answer (score 2):

This is applicable to Google Messenger version 1.8.268 updated on 17 May 2016.

Go to Settings>Advanced>MMS>Group messaging

Select "Send individual SMS messages..."

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

The only solution I found to this issue was to install [Textra app.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.textra)