# LG G3 - 4.4.2 - Stop SMS converting to MMS

Tags: sms, mms

I used to have Nexus 4, I was able to disable SMS converting to MMS. It did not convert my messages to MMS when I do group messaging. 
Now I have **LG G3** with Andorid 4.4.2, when when I do group messaging, it sends it as MMS automatically. 
i went to Messaging Menu - Creation Mode - Set it to "Restricted". it still does that. Is there any way to stop MMS completely?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Similar questions have been asked here before and might be helpful for you. Please see the "related" section of this page: [How can I prevent my device from automatically converting SMS to MMS?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/4142/16575) / [Sending single SMS message to multiple contacts causes MMS](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/45901/16575), also [Send SMS instead of MMS when texting multiple people](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/58707/16575).

Comment: Thanks Izzy. I have read through the answer already before posting the question. Almost all of them lead to this setting - "Under "Multimedia (MMS) Messages, uncheck the item that says: "Group messaging- Use MMS to send a single message when there are multiple recipients". but I don't have that option. Hence the reason for my question. i was able to do this on my Nexus 4. LG G3 does not seem to have it. Hard to believe a new phone would not support it.

Comment: Thanks for the additional details! Good to see you did your research before posting your question. Hint: in such cases, it's good to point that out in the question as well ("what you've tried and where that failed") – so people know they don't need to recommend the same things again :) // Sorry, as someone who rarely uses even SMS, I unfortunately cannot be of further assistance here. Good luck – hopefully someone else jumps in soon!

Answer (score 1):

So what you need to do is; before you create the message, when you are at the screen where all of your text messages show up, tap the menu button in the to right of the screen. Then tap settings and go to multimedia message. Once there uncheck the box that says Group Messaging. This can only be done from the screen where you see all your other text messages and can create a new message. Not once you are in the text itself. Hope this helps.